# Apple Match-O Linker Error / clang: error: no such file or directory - Xcode 11

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, react-native, clang

I am working on a React Native application and whenever I try to build the application I am encountering these errors. I know there are many similar questions on this matter but the solutions given there are not working for me.

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTRestart.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libReactNativePermissions.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNCPushNotificationIOS.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNReanimated.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNGestureHandler.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNMixpanel.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNCAsyncStorage.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTAnimation.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNVectorIcons.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNReactNativeDocViewer.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNFS.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCodePush.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNDocumentPicker.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNImagePicker.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNI18n.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNBlur.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libART.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTVideo.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTActionSheet.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTGeolocation.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTImage.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTLinking.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTNetwork.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTSettings.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTText.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTVibration.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTWebSocket.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNSpinkit.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNSentry.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNGeocoder.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRCTContacts.a'
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blonk-eatmzbgmhuzfadfqxgotpiqwsapb/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRNOpenAppSettings.a'
```

I have searched but I am still stuck here. I have tried linking using `react-native link`. I have tried deleting the `DerivedData` folder for the application. Hence I have tried everything but can't seem to find a solution for this. So I turned to you guys please suggest any solution to fix this. Looking forward to your answers. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why haven't you told your compiler where to look for libraries? The `-L` option.

Comment: @JesperJuhl ... where should I add the -L flag ? should i add it in the "Other Linker Flags" option in the build settings ?

Comment: I have no idea where you should add it in your IDE of choice. I'm only telling you what the argument you need to pass to the compiler should be. How you achieve that is *your* problem.

Comment: Yes add it to Other LInker Flags. It should work.

Comment: I have added -L to other linker flags in build settings but it did not work

Comment: What version of React Native are you using?

Comment: This application was on 0.48.0 i have updated it to 0.59.10

Comment: just check your code there should be a duplicate file.

Comment: Duplicated file in the linked libraries?

Comment: What have you tried?! Step one: blow away `/Users/FaisalHussain/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: Have you tried to compile onto a device. Are these libraries yours/built or external? Do they have a version that runs on the simulator?

Comment: If you have upgraded your react-native version, please follow this helper: react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper

Comment: I am facing same issue, any solution found ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using cocoapods, which is very likely the case given the recent versions of rn, try the following:

1. Enter the `ios` folder.

```sh
$ cd ios
```

2. If you don't have `cocoapods` installed, try running:

```sh
$ gem install cocoapods # Try with `sudo` if it doesn't work.
```

You may also consider locking the cocoapods version for your project, read more [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/using/a-gemfile.html#using-cocoapods-with-a-gemfile).

3. Run `pod install`.
4. Then make sure to open the file with the `.xcworkspace` extension.

Finally, try building again.

Comment: I have already gone through this procedure before but it isn't working. Still getting the same errors. Any other suggestions ?

Comment: Maybe clearing the project and deleting the `DerivedData` folder before running the above instructions will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen that you upgraded from 0.48 to 0.59. That is a lot of versions and a lot of breaking changes to jump to.

My suggestion, create a new, clean 0.59.10 project and then slowly move all your code and dependencies to the new one. There are so many things to try and check. Probably your header search paths are wrong or outdated.

Perhaps a dependency does not support your RN version anymore. Or maybe you have a missing library in the linked-libraries list.

To be honest, too many things to try. Just do a new project, from scratch, and start adding your dependencies one by one.

Comment: I suspect creating a new project from scratch would be a pain because the previous developer has used lots of dependencies and code added to appdelagte.m for some of the dependencies. Also there is a issue with the package name there different package names for android and ios

Comment: As you wish, but in my experience migrating and jumping several versions like that, I always end up doing it from scratch.

Comment: What other option do i have ? If you can see in my question only those dependencies are giving this error. I have updated these dependencies as well

Comment: It’s really not that bad, and upgrading to a more recent version (around 60) is highly advisable and contains many improvements.

Comment: Just because 0.60 has many improvements does not necessary mean that you should upgrade. 0.60 breaks dependencies with the change to support only androidx. Many many dependencies have not switched nor make the change so if you have some specific dependency that you are using, it will break for good. Jetifier also does not always work. Upgrading RN has always felt very dangerous for me, but maybe I am talking about complex projects.

Comment: I agree with @sfratini ... I have many dependencies installed that were not updated for the past 3 years so instead of upgrading to 0.60 I decided to upgrade to 0.59.10 and when the upgrade is complete and the app is release then will work on replacing those obsolete dependencies and then upgrade to the latest stable version of RN

Answer (score 0):

Can you go through following steps:

```
Delete node_modules
Delete package-lock.json
Delete ios/Pods directory
Delete Podfile.lock file
```

Then run following commands one by one from your terminal.

```
cd root/project directory
npm install 
cd ios/ && pod install && cd ..
```

Then try to build your app

```
react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Ok let me go through these steps and get back to you

Comment: I hope it will work, however if you still face issues, please let me know here.

Comment: No luck still the same ... these the error i am getting https://pastebin.com/FyuVZqCy

Comment: Can you please open Xcode and then build/run your app to see what error it will show to you??